# How to avoid NaN in np.where between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have customer data, and want to check if their emails are present in a separate df using np.where, which returns 'match' or 'no match'.

However one of the customer emails is NaN, and one of the emails in the second df is nan, so this comes back as a match. As you can see a match was found for Mr. stack overflow.

```
customers = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['stack','Bar Bar','Foo Bar','jim','john','mary','jim'],
                   'lastname':['overflow','Bar','Foo Bar','ryan','con','sullivan','Ryan'],
                   'email':[np.nan,'Bar','Foo Bar','jim@com','john@com','mary@com','Jim@com']})

customers

    firstname   lastname    email
0   jim             bob             NaN
1   Bar Bar     Bar     bar@com
2   Foo Bar     Foo Bar     foo@com
3   jim     ryan        jim@com
4   john        con     john@com
5   mary        sullivan    hello@com
6   jim     Ryan        jon@com
```

Now I want to check if their emails are in another dataframe called 'emails' below:

```
emails = pd.DataFrame({'emails':['mary@com','bar@com','foo@com','jim@com','john@com',np.nan,'jon@com']})

emails

    emails
0   mary@com
1   bar@com
2   foo@com
3   jim@com
4   john@com
5   NaN
6   jon@com
```

I'll create a new column called 'check' which will record the result of the check as either 'match' or 'no match'

```
customers['check'] = np.where(customers['email'].isin(emails['emails']), 'match', 'no_match')

customers


    firstname   lastname    email       check
0   jim     bob     NaN     match
1   Bar Bar     Bar     bar@com     match
2   Foo Bar     Foo Bar     foo@com     match
3   jim     ryan        jim@com     match
4   john        con     john@com    match
5   mary        sullivan    hello@com   no_match
6   jim     Ryan        jon@com     match
```

Everything looks fine except for jim bob's record. His email is NaN, there's a NaN in the email dataframe. So it returns as a match.

What's the best way to get around this?

I was thinking of doing something drastic like `fillna()` and change it to a string like `'fakeNaN'` or something, so it doesn't come up with a match. But there must be a better way.

**edit:** I have just tried this:

Defined a function to use with lambda, returning no_email if the customer doesn't have an email.

```
def lam(r):

# if the email is nan, return no_email

    if r == np.nan:
        return 'no_email'

    elif r in emails['emails']:
        return 'match'

    elif not r in emails['emails']:
        return 'no_match'

# apply this lambda operation to the customer email row and return results to customer['check']

customers['check'] = customers.apply(lambda row: lam(row['email']), axis=1)
```

However it now returns no_match for everything. There are a few matches.

```
0    no_match
1    no_match
2    no_match
3    no_match
4    no_match
5    no_match
6    no_match
dtype: object
```

**edit2:** i've noticed somthing strange now.

I can check `emails['emails']` and see that `jim@com` is there:

```
emails['emails']

0    mary@com
1     bar@com
2     foo@com
3     jim@com
4    john@com
5         NaN
6     jon@com
Name: emails, dtype: object
```

so why doesn't this work?

```
'jim@com' in emails['emails']

False
```

Comment: you mean ```'jim@com' in list(emails['emails'])```?  ```emails['emails']``` is a pandas series.

Comment: `in` doesn't work for series? I didn't know. Now I do.

Comment: Like a dictionary, ```in``` will only check the key(index) of a pandas series. so try ```1 in emails['emails']```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isin` with `np.select`

```
m1=customers.email.isin(emails.emails.dropna().values)
m2=customers.email.notna()
customers['check']=np.select([m1&m2,~m1&m2],['match','no match'],default='no_email')
customers
  firstname  lastname     email     check
0     stack  overflow       NaN  no_email        
1   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar  no match
2   Foo Bar   Foo Bar   Foo Bar  no match
3       jim      ryan   jim@com     match
4      john       con  john@com     match
5      mary  sullivan  mary@com     match
6       jim      Ryan   Jim@com  no match
```

Comment: The NaN is still being 'matched' though. It's not really a match you see. Maybe check my edit to see exactly what I'm trying to do with my lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Saved emails as pandas series. Slightly unorthodox approach.

`*1` for casting boolean to integer.

```
emails = pd.Series(['mary@com','bar@com','foo@com','jim@com','john@com',np.nan,'jon@com'])

(customers['email'].isin(emails)*1+customers['email'].isnull()*1).map({0:'No-Match',1:'Match',2:'No-Record'})

0   No-Record
1   No-Match
2   No-Match
3   Match
4   Match
5   Match
6   No-Match
```

Comment: This works perfectly . But I'm gonna have to go with WeNYoBen's answer as it's just a bit more readable and easier to explain. Thanks for your help and comments though, you've given me some ideas if I want to re-visit my lambda function.

Comment: @SCool No prob. Using booleans to create numeric categories sometimes save you a lot of time.